# display('string:'.$template_string) do not work

Tags: php, html, templates, smarty, smarty3

I tried to use

```
$template = "<h1>Hello {name},</h1>";
$smarty->assign('name','Christian');
$output = $smarty->fetch('string:' . $template);
echo $output;
```

Result is:

```
Hello ,
```

it output the template, but do not show the variables in the template. I use the latest Smarty 3.1.32 What is wrong Thanks for help Christian

Comment: According to https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl it looks like you're missing a `$` in `{name}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variables in smarty like in php. So it should be: `$template = "<h1>Hello {$name},</h1>";`.